# Visualize complement of spheres

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $A=S^n-h(S^k)$ and $B=S^n-h(S^l)$, where $h$ denotes embedding of $S^k$, $S^l$ into the $n$-sphere $S^n$.

How do we see that

1) $A\cup B=S^n$

2) $A\cap B=S^n-\text{a point}=R^n$.

I can't seem to visualize or get any intuition why the above 2 are true.

Thanks.

Motivation:

I wish to calculate the homology $H_i(S^n-(S^k\vee S^l))$ using Mayer-Vietoris, hence splitting the space into $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Doesn't this depend on how $S^k$ and $S^l$ are embedded into $S^n$?  I mean, (a) relies on those embeddings being disjoint, doesn't it?

Comment: Also, how can (b) be true?  Don't we have $A \cap B \subset A$?

Comment: H is an embedding of what, exactly?

Comment: I imagine that these $h$s are fixed embeddings. Unless the OP tells us what they are, we can't solve the problem.

Comment: Good points. Unfortunately, I don't know how is it embedded. Is there such thing as a canonical embedding? I can provide the motivation for my question though (in the main question above).

Comment: Consider a simple case n = 3, k = 2, l  = 3 that can be easily visulized.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Thanks. How do I visualize $S^3$ which lies in fourth dimension?

Comment: Right.  Substract one from the

Comment: Right.  Let n = 2, k = 1, l = 1 for example.  Is h actually the same for both embeddings?

Comment: @WilliamElliot I am not sure..

Comment: @yoyostein.  Why not?  It's allowed as well as l = 1.  S^1 however, isn't connected, which perhaps would make a didderence.